# Can I use Civi platform to set up an online store?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

Since we cant hold events due to Covid-19, I suggested opening an online store so we could sell tshirts, stickers, and other swag as a fundraiser.
I set up a Contribution page, and am using a price set for the items. But that seems cumbersome, and doesnt allow much flexibility. For instance, each item is its own line-
"Hammer" Blue T-Shirt, Size Small"
"Hammer" Blue T-Shirt, Size Medium"

Is there a way I could create the page to say,
"Hammer Shirt" and then a drop down for size and color info?

Comment: I do not know of a way that you can allow both 'quantity' and colour/size to be set on a single field via a Price Set. If you are using Drupal or WP you may get closer via Webforms or Caldera forms

Comment: you could use the price set tools to create options for sizes and colours for the shirt.

Comment: Could you say which CMS you're using Wordpress, Dupal, Joomla ?